# Imagine that there is an infinite grid, within which each box contains an integer

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question on the Infinity Grid and integers

Imagine that there is an infinite grid, within which each box contains an integer. Prove that the only way each box has a value that is less than or equal to the mean of the values in the 4 surrounding it, is if every box is equal.

Comment: What are your own thoughts? Where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: How is the "mean" of a box calculated?

Comment: What happens if you write the integer $|m|+|n|$ in the box with coordinates $(m,n)$? Isn't the number in each box less than or equal to the average of the numbers in the four neighboring boxes?

Comment: Yes.... a very difficult concept for me as a starter of pure maths.... working based on tips from all of you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not true. If one assigns box $(x,y)$ the number $x^2+y^2$, then we have

$$\frac{(x+1)^2+y^2+x^2+(y+1)^2+(x-1)^2+y^2+x^2+(y-1)^2}{4}=\frac{4x^2+4y^2+4}{4}=x^2+y^2+1>x^2+y^2,$$

so each box has a value $\leq$ the average of the values in its neighboring boxes.

However, if the problem were asking you to show that each number must be the same if each box has a value $\geq$ the average of the values in its neighboring boxes, AND the boxes must each have **positive** integers, then it would be true (I suspect this is what the original problem asked). To show this, think about a box that contains the smallest positive integer contained by any box, and go outwards.

Comment: Instead of assuming two errors in the transmission, we could assume just one error: the numbers in the boxes are **negative** integers. That's maximum likelihood decoding. :-)

Comment: @bof That works too.

Comment: Thanks all for the prompt response....I am studying pure maths by myself and do not understand the whole theory and application of this Grid concept.  I am trying again based on tips from you.  :)

Comment: @JCheung If you have any questions about my answer, feel free to ask.